# Fitting upper and lower student-t separately

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-distribution, marginal-distribution, heavy-tailed

I'm doing some research on fitting marginal distributions to data, in particular distributions with a focus on heavy tails. In one report, albeit several years old, the authors suggested fitting a Student-T but fitting the lower and upper tails separately. That is they split the series into negative and positive returns, and after some manipulations, created two separate marginals: one for upper and one for lower. They then "pasted" as it were the two distributions together.

My question is whether this is a statistically sound practice. Aside from the fact that other heavy-tailed distributions exist, is the practice of pasting together two distributions sound. My inclination is to say no, but I was wondering if anyone was able to offer a better explanation.

Comment: Could you please explain by what you mean with pasting together two distributions being sound? Are you uncertain whether it yields a valid probability distribution? Whether inference (what sort?) using that new distribution is sound?

Comment: Mainly whether using those distributions to build a multivariate distribution would yield a mathematically sound result or whether sampling (i.e. finding the t-stat with a p-value of x) would be valid. Essentially I think I am asking whether the probability distribution constructed this way is mathematically valid

Comment: You just used the word "sound" to define what you mean by "sound"; that's not as helpful as you might hope.

Comment: Did you consider using skew-$t$ distribution instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Francisco Rubio and Mark Steel recently published a [paper in Bayesian Analysis](http://bayesian.org/BA/5229) entitled “Inference in two-piece location-scale models with Jeffreys priors”. Paper where they consider the skewed distribution
$$
\dfrac{2\epsilon}{\sigma_1}f(\{x-\mu\}/\sigma_1)\mathbb{I}_{x<\mu}+\dfrac{2(1-\epsilon)}{\sigma_2}f(\{x-\mu\}/\sigma_2) \mathbb{I}_{x>\mu}
\qquad0<\epsilon<1
$$
where f is a symmetric density. Most of the paper is about Jeffreys priors for such distributions, but it contains a description of a practical estimation of such split models, which would also apply in your setting.

Comment: As suggested by [panadol](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/91344/panadol), there is a recent paper by the same authors that uses distributions with different tail behaviour: [Bayesian modelling of skewness and kurtosis with Two-Piece Scale and shape distributions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1440680330)